# How to fix this strange java exception when running a Gradle script in Cygwin?

Tags: java, gradle, cygwin

Trying to replicate some tests locally and ran into a problem.

It's a basic script. My simple Gradle task:

```
task runJSUnitTests(type:Exec) {
    logger.warn('Starting the JS Unit Tests >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ' + )
    commandLine 'deploy/scripts/RunJSDTests_win.sh', 'unit', JSTD_SERVER_PORT, PYTHON_SERVER_PORT
}
```

Then I just have a blank-ish RunJSDTests_win.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "What's up?"

# TODO: put script back when this error is resolved

exit
```

**But it produces this Java error**

`Cannot run program "./deploy/scripts/RunJSDTests_win.sh" (in directory "C:\SomeProjectRoot\"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

**Additionally, I get this error:**

`No publish configurations specified for project ':' and the default 'archives' configuration does not exist.`

If I do java -version at the bash prompt I get 
java version "1.7.0_55"

Comment: It would appear that cygwin\bin is not in the PATH when it attempts to execute RunJSDTests_win.sh?

Comment: Hm. I added C:\cygwin64\bin to PATH. Still get same error. Do I need to set an additional path in Cygwin (not just windows)?

Comment: I'm not sure, I am wondering if it's running that task outside of the CYGWIN environment... Can you run the test script directly?

Comment: Running the script directly from bash works. I also tried adding the full path to bash in the commandline parameter string.

Comment: Sounds like it might be necessary to invoke `/bin/sh` explicitly under Cygwin, like it's necessary to invoke `cmd` explicitly under Windows (for executing batch scripts). PS: From my limited personal experience, I wouldn't recommend to run Gradle under Cygwin. It's also not an officially tested environment.